# how can I add percentage to the barchart in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

This code gives me a bar chart but I also want to insert the percentage, how will I go about it?

```
Hipertension_factor = appointments.groupby(['No-show'])['Hipertension'].count()
Hipertension_factor.plot(kind = 'bar', title = 'Hipertension')
plt.xlabel('No-show', fontsize = 18)
plt.ylabel('Hipertension', fontsize = 18)
```

Comment: you should explicitly show what kind of library you are using for the barchart

Answer (score 0):

We cannot provide code to solve your problem, but there are many ways to annotate plots in `matplotlib` (which I will assume you are using) as shown here

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/annotation_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-annotation-demo-py

Where a basic example is:

```
ax.annotate('straight',
    xy=(0, 1), xycoords='data',
    xytext=(-50, 30), textcoords='offset points',
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
```

You will just need to calculate the percentages using a standard `count or what you want`/`total count of possibilities` formula and then you can plot the results using the same x,y as you used to create the bar graph, and include a string with the percentage you just calculated (replacing 'straight' in the example above). This question also does not have a direct answer because you may want to annotate slightly off your bars which will be different than plotting exactly on your bars...